# Frontend design for rest service

Tags: php, rest, jquery

I'm currently working on a rest service writen in c++/qt and i'm also thinking about the future web ui who will use this service.

I admit i'm not super expert in html/js since i've always worked on the back-end side, and i'm not sure how the modern ui patterns are today.
As first question i aks: is a html/js only ui (accessing the rest service directly) a better / worst choice than a html/js ui with a server side php layer who will act as support for consuming the rest service (js ask to php who ask to rest)?

Thanks in advance.
Ivan.

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a backend that was designed following the principles of REST, it is in my opinion the better approach to let the Web frontend communicate directly to the API of the backend.

The views you have to provide in the frontend match well to the application states (URLs) of your backend. The backend should implement the so-called hypermedia principle, i.e. it provides links to the allowed next application states and the frontend should respect this information.

In other words: what's wrong with your REST backend that you think it might be better to have another layer on top of it?